# Prove that the ideal of $\mathbb{C}G$ generated by a family of elements $\lbrace p_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$ is equal to $\mathbb{C}G$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, characters, group-algebras

Given a finite abelian group $G$ consider the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$ and a set $\mathcal{P}=\lbrace p_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$ of elements of $\mathbb{C}G$. Define $I$ to be the ideal of $\mathbb{C}G$ generated by $\mathcal{P}$. I want to find a condition to ensure that $I\neq\mathbb{C}G$.

By representation theory of finite groups, since $G$ is a finite abelian group, every irreducible representation fo $\mathbb{C}G$ has dimension $1$. Hence $\mathbb{C}G$ decomposes as a direct sum:
$$\mathbb{C}G\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^{|G|}\mathbb{C}e_i$$
where $\lbrace e_i\rbrace_{i=1}^{|G|}$ is a set of elements such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{|G|}e_i=1$ (for example if $G=C_n$ then it is the set of $n$-th roots of unity)

Now, we know that there is a bijection between the set of characters of $G$ and sums of elements of $e_i$. Hence, if $e$ is defined as the sum of some $e_i$ and $\chi_e$ is its corresponding character then $\forall~\lambda=\sum\limits_{g\in G}\alpha_g g\in\mathbb{C}G$ we have:
$$\lambda e=\left(\sum\limits_{g\in G}\alpha_g \chi_e(g)\right)e$$
and, this affects in the decomposition as:
$$\lambda\mathbb{C}G=\bigoplus_{\lambda\cdot e_i\neq 0}\mathbb{C}e_i$$
In particular, this means that if there is a character $\chi:G\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\chi(p_i)=0~\forall~i=1,\dots,n$ then:
$$p_i \mathbb{C}G\neq\mathbb{C}G~\forall~i=1,\dots,n$$
This proves the following:

**If there exists a character $\chi:G\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\chi(p_i)=0~\forall~i=1,\dots,n$ then $I\neq\mathbb{C}G$**

Is it correct? I've recently started to learn chacter theory, so I'm not sure if this makes any sense. In the case where the proof is incorrect I would like to know whether the final result is true or not. Tanks for your feedback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is basically correct.

A character $\chi\colon G\to \mathbb{C}^\times$ [note it should take values in the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers] induces an algebra homomorphism $\tilde{\chi}\colon \mathbb{C}G\to \mathbb{C}$ given by $\tilde{\chi}:=\tilde\chi(\sum \alpha_g g)=\sum \alpha_g \chi(g)$.
Moreover the kernel of $\tilde{\chi}$, $$ \ker \tilde{\chi}:=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}G:\tilde{\chi}(\lambda)=0\}$$ is always a proper ideal of $\mathbb{C}G$, that is not equal to $\mathbb{C}G$, by the rank-nullity theorem, for example.

Your condition that $\tilde{\chi}(p_i)=0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ forces $I=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ to be contained in the kernel of $\tilde{\chi}$ and so not equal to $\mathbb{C}G$.

In fact the converse is also true, since every maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}G$ is the kernel of some $\tilde{\chi}$, and so every proper ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{C}G$ is contained in some $\ker \tilde{\chi}$. Moreover for this choice of $\chi$, $\tilde{\chi}(p)=0$ for all $p\in I$ and so in particular for all $p$ in a generating set for $I$.

Comment: And if $G$ is non-abelian, the condition is just... there exists an irrep $\phi$ so that the block matrix with blocks $\phi(p_i)^T$ is not full rank.

Comment: I guess that depends whether ideal means left ideal or two-sided ideal?

Comment: Yes, good point, this is for one-sided ideals. I guess two-sided ideals will need to entirely zero out an irrep!

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon can you elaborate more on that? I've tried to solve this problem  with $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ and $G$ finite abelian because it seemed to be the esiest possible case. But if there is a way to solve the same problem for a group algebra $\mathbb{F}G$ with $\mathbb{F}$ an arbitrary field and $G$ an arbitrary finite group I would be also interested.

Comment: @Marcos Yes, and it will also work for any submodule of a free module. This is a good example of how staying organized about tensor and hom can make tricky calculations into simple ones. Try homming your right ideal to a right simple module and see what you get. (Alternatively, you could mod out by your ideal and tensor with a left simple). I'm happy to provide more details, but probably not in a comment.

Comment: The crucial thing for more general arguments along the lines I gave is the Artin-Wedderburn Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%E2%80%93Artin_theorem. $\mathbb{F}G$ is a semisimple $\mathbb{F}$-algebra whenever $G$ is a finite group whose order is coprime to the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}$ (plus the case where the latter is $0$). As I hinted before the problem has two generalisations in the non-commutative setting depending on whether you wish 'ideal' to mean two-sided or one-sided ideals.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to say it is that, if we label so that the character $\chi$ is associated to the primitive idempotent $e$ of the group algebra, then $e$ does not appear in the expression of any $p_{i}$ as a linear combination of the primitive idempotents. Hence $e$ does not appear in the expression  of $x$ as a linear combination of primitive idempotents for any $x$ in $I$. Thus, in particular, $e$ lies outside $I$, and $I$ is a proper ideal. This is just another way of saying what @SimonWadsley said.